# .slideToggle(); doesn't works when clicking on a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a specific text is clicked, a hidden div (hidden with .hide();) should appear. Then, when said text is clicked again, the div should hide and la, la, la...

Simple, but it doesn't works.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <a id="idMakam" class="artistas">Makam</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infoMakam" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p class="infoArtistas">Nacido y criado en la costa holandesa, <b>Makam</b> golpeó un nervio creativo que impulsó su talento crudo a temprana edad. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Toogles de +info de artistas:
    $("#infoMakam").hide(); //Primero los esconde.
    $("#idMakam").click(function(){
        $("#infoMakam").slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Working fine for me

Comment: yes it is working

Comment: Okai, I may have found the issue: but first, when will this site comprehen pressing enter is for a new line?

Anyway... I was thinking the BootStrap jQuery would work, but it doesn't. I linked pure jQuery and voilá.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Toogles de +info de artistas:
    $("#infoMakam").hide(); //Primero los esconde.
    $("#idMakam").click(function(){
        $("#infoMakam").slideToggle(200);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <a id="idMakam" class="artistas">Makam</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infoMakam" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p class="infoArtistas">Nacido y criado en la costa holandesa, <b>Makam</b> golpeó un nervio creativo que impulsó su talento crudo a temprana edad. </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't find what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I just copy pasted your code in plunker and it is working.

check for any errors? did you include jquery library?

```js
// Code goes here
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Toogles de +info de artistas:
    $("#infoMakam").hide(); //Primero los esconde.
    $("#idMakam").click(function(){
        $("#infoMakam").slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <a id="idMakam" class="artistas">Makam</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infoMakam" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p class="infoArtistas">Nacido y criado en la costa holandesa, <b>Makam</b> golpeó un nervio creativo que impulsó su talento crudo a temprana edad. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I know it is correctly linked since it hides the div.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, your code should work fine. My only thought is if there is other javascript in your file conflicting with the .toggle()? I'm assuming your code has more than just what is given, so if not please disregard. If there is, check that there aren't any other javascript statements that conflict with the hidden div, so that it will not toggle. I have had the issue happen previously, so just a thought you might want to check. The code as given works perfectly!